# Why VisualVm and JOL tools give different results for object size

Tags: java, visualvm, jol

I've tried to measure size of one instance of the class A:

```
package pkg;
class A {
    private int i;
}
```

Result using VisualVm was 20 bytes:
[image]

But result using JOL was 16 bytes:

```
pkg.A object internals:
 OFFSET  SIZE   TYPE DESCRIPTION                               VALUE
      0    12        (object header)                           N/A
     12     4    int A.i                                       N/A
Instance size: 16 bytes
Space losses: 0 bytes internal + 0 bytes external = 0 bytes total
```

Here is complete code I was using for this test:

```
package pkg;

import org.openjdk.jol.info.ClassLayout;

import static java.lang.System.out;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        A a = new A();
        out.println(ClassLayout.parseClass(A.class).toPrintable());
    }
}

class A {
    private int i;
}
```

Have I misuse this tools or misinterpret its results?
I was expecting to have same results from both tools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not going to like it probably... But `VisualVM` lies, as pretty much explained [here](https://shipilev.net/blog/2014/heapdump-is-a-lie/) (there is a much more in depth video from the same great Shipilev, but I can't seem to find it)

Trust `JOL`, it's correctly showing you the result.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using `ClassLayout.parseClass(A.class)`.

If you want to measure memory utilization of `a` (instance of `A`), try

```
ClassLayout.parseInstance(a).toPrintable()
```

Comment: I've changed the test to use `ClassLayout.parseInstance(a)` but size of the object is still 16 bytes acording to JOL